# How do I evaluate this specific JSON with Prototype(JS)?

Tags: php, json, prototypejs

Data from a Server became a JSON array as responseText an ajax request :

```
Price : [{"id":"1","max_price":"100000"},{"id":"2","max_price":"150000"},{"id":"3","max_price":"200000.55"}]

Name : [{"id":"1","name":"P1"},{"id":"2","name":"P2"},{"id":"3","name":"P3"}]
```

I see into Prototype this method : `var json = transport.responseText.evalJSON(true);`

How can I just get the Price array, so JSON equals:

```
[{"id":"1","max_price":"100000"},{"id":"2","max_price":"150000"},{"id":"3","max_price":"200000.55"}]`
```

Comment: The data you supplied is actually not valid json. Is this *exactly* what the server is sending you?

Comment: i think it should have been `"price":...` and `"name":...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The php needs to include the json header:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

The ajax request needs to include evalScripts (make sure you trust the source):

```
new Ajax.Request("json.php",
          { method: 'get',
            parameters: {'xyz': 'json', 'var2': 'some_val'},
            evalScripts: true,
            onSuccess: function(response){your_function(response);}});
```

Then your function can get the json like the following:

```
your_function = function (response) {
  var result = response.responseJSON;
  ...
}
```

---

Edit: There's also these instructions directly from the source:
http://www.prototypejs.org/learn/json

---

Edit2: Here's how to update the server:

```
$return_data = array();
$return_data['price'] = getPrice($db); 
$return_data['name'] = getName($db);
echo json_encode($return_data)."\n";
```

after you do this, in js you can do something like the following (from the above your_function example):

```
alert ("first id is: " + result['price'][0]['id']);
```

Comment: Doh, and now I see that what you're getting from the server isn't proper JSON, so this technique won't work.  I'd suggest fixing the server if possible.

Comment: fixing the Server? but how? i use this on the Server : `$price = json_encode(getPrice($db));
        $name = json_encode(getName($db));        
        echo "Price : ", $price, "\n"; echo "Name : ", $name, "\n";`  That's already JSON isnt?

Comment: That's 2 json strings and some other data that make it unusable by the built-in methods.  Either pass a parameter to the php to indicate which var you want (price or name) and only `echo json_encode(...);` or merge the two objects and `json_encode` the merged object.  I'll update with an example.